# create replica of ext4 filesystem and re-use it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, filesystems

Is there a way that I can use my Linux ext4 file system, as such and then use it on some other computer.

I have a dual-boot of Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.04 and my partition table looks like this:

[image: My partition table]

My question might not be clear, so explaining it with an example.

Can I copy my Linux partition on a flash drive and then use it on a different PC, with or without any need to install Ubuntu on new PC, by simply booting from the copied ext4 partition.
This way, I can easily port my Ubuntu packages and other applications, settings etc. from one PC to other.

If it's a very stupid question, please don't mind.

Comment: ...why did you post the table as a _picture_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The simplest way is to create an empty partition of exactly the same size<sup>1</sup>, then `cp` or `dd` over the data.

   ```
   cp INPUT OUTPUT
   dd if=INPUT of=OUTPUT
   pv INPUT > OUTPUT
   ```

   Pick one. For example, if you were to copy from `/dev/sda3` to `/dev/sdc1`, you would use `pv /dev/sda3 > /dev/sdc1` or `dd if=/dev/sda3 of=/dev/sdc1`.

   (You can copy into a regular file too, but it wouldn't be easily *bootable*, although you *can* loop-mount such a copy in an already-running system.)
2. To make the copy bootable, you will need to install a bootloader into the flash drive.

   `grub` would work, but I'm not sure if the latest version supports specifying the root partition by UUID. (It used to be an Ubuntu-specific patch.) UUIDs are needed because `grub` needs a filesystem identifier that stays the same among computers.

---

<sup>1</sup> The partition and the filesystem store their sizes independently; therefore, the partition must be as big as the filesystem thinks it is. You *can* create a larger partition and later grow the copied filesystem, though. Most filesystems can be shrunk too.

Comment: Thanks. However, making the copy bootable and how the partition and filesystem store their sizes independently, is quite unclear. Can you guide me through a tutorial or an article which explains this.